# How to change tag's inner html to the username?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change (div.class=loguser)'s innerhtml to the username that has logged in. To get the username, I wrote a function that gets input of username and password from the register_button which is inside (div#register). I wrote an object(addData) which takes the username and password and stores it in an array(datas). After putting it in the array, I made a function where it verifies if the username and password exists in the array. If it does exist, it is suppose the change the innerhtml to the username. But it is not working. And I cant even submit the form while registering.

```js
let datas = [];
const addData = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = {
    username: document.getElementById('rusername').value,
    password: document.getElementById('rpassword').value
  }
  datas.push(data);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('register_button').addEventListener('click', addData);
});

function isUserValid(username, password) {
  var username = document.getElementById('lusername').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    if (datas[i].username === username &&
      datas[i].password === password) {
      var name = username;
      document.getElementsByClassName('loguser').innerHTML = username;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="loguser">
    <td>
      <ul class="nav-area">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">User</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </td>
  </div>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="login_box">
      <div class="login_header">
        <img src="images/alimama.png" alt=""> <br> Login or Register!
      </div>

      <div id="login">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="lusername" type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="lpassword" type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="register">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="rusername" type="text" name="rusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="rpassword" type="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Password" required>
          <br>
          <input id="register_button" type="submit" name="register_button" value="Register">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Sign in here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: You never call `isUserValid()`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('loguser')` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. You need to index it to assign to its `innerHTML`. And if you assign to this, you're completely replacing all the markup in the DIV.

Comment: You have `</table>` but no `<table>`. Did you leave out lots of the HTML?

Comment: I suspect the element you want to put the username in is `<a href="#">User</a>`. Give that an ID and assign to its innerHTML.

Comment: @Barmar Yes i shortened the code by removing other stuff from the table, it had a dropdown, but i want to replace everything there and want it to only print the username that has logged in, in that place..So if i call ```isUserValid()``` at the bottom, would it solve the problem?

Comment: Add an event listener to `login_button` that calls `isUserValid`.

Comment: @Barmar i added ```document.getElementById('login_button').addEventListener('click', isUserValid());``` at the end,, but the problem is it doesnt even register when i click register button, it doesnt work

Comment: `isUserValid()` should be `isUserValid`. Just like the way you add the other event listener.

Comment: @Barmar i added ```document.getElementById('login_button').addEventListener('click', isUserValid);``` still doesnt work...for some reason i cant register, to add the username and password in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isUserValid()` shouldn't take `username` and `password` as parameters, since it gets them from the inputs. It should take an event parameter, so you can call it as an event listener.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`. You need to use `[0]` to access the first match to set its `innerHTML`. You could also use `document.querySelector()`, it just returns the first match.

The login button doesn't have an ID. Add `id="login_button"` so you can add an event listener to it.

Instead of your loop you can use the `find()` method to search an array.

```js
let datas = [];
const addData = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = {
    username: document.getElementById('rusername').value,
    password: document.getElementById('rpassword').value
  }
  datas.push(data);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('register_button').addEventListener('click', addData);
});

function isUserValid(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = document.getElementById('lusername').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;
  var found_user = datas.find(d => d.username === username && d.password === password);
  if (found_user) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('loguser')[0].innerHTML = found_user.username;
  }
}

document.getElementById("login_button").addEventListener("click", isUserValid);
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="loguser">
    User
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="login_box">
      <div class="login_header">
        <img src="images/alimama.png" alt=""> <br> Login or Register!
      </div>

      <div id="login">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="lusername" type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="lpassword" type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" id="login_button" name="login_button" value="Login">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="register">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="rusername" type="text" name="rusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="rpassword" type="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Password" required>
          <br>
          <input id="register_button" type="submit" name="register_button" value="Register">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Sign in here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! sorry cant upvote since i dont have much reputation

Comment: How do i take the variable in a different page? to have it in the same session?

Comment: You should submit the form, it will receive the input fields as parameters.

Comment: Can you please comment the code? sorry im a beginner.. thank you

Comment: should I do ```onclick="isUserValid()"```?

Comment: No, that's what `document.getElementById("login_button").addEventListener("click", isUserValid)` does

Comment: can you please give me the code for submitting the form so it receives the input fields as parameters? Thank you!

Comment: should i do ```onsubmit="isUserValid()"```

Comment: You can use `onsubmit="isUserValid(event)"`. The function should then take an `event` parameter so it can do `event.preventDefault()` when the user isn't valid.

Comment: BTW, it's wrong to do user authentication in the client, since the user can easily get around it. It should be done on the server.

Comment: I know but my professor told me to do it for the assignment anyways.. and i put the ```onsubmit="isUserValid(event)"``` in the login button,, but it just shows the username in the login page and not in any other pages.

Comment: is there any way i could put it in a local storage so it stays even if i go to another page of the website?

Comment: Of course you can. `localStorage.setItem("username", username)`. Put that in `isUserValid()` when it determines that the username/password is valid.

Comment: inside the if statement i put this but it still wont allow me to take the variable in other html pages,,i could only view it on the login page ```if (found_user) {
        localStorage.setItem("username", username);
        var x = localStorage.getItem("username");
        document.getElementsByClassName('loguser')[0].innerHTML = x;//found_user.username; 
    }``

Comment: The form needs an action to specify the other page to go to.

Comment: If the other page wants to show the user name, it needs to use `username = localStorage.getItem("username");` and then display it there.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, don't you have teaching material that explains all this?

Comment: ,,,its a short session, so its like 4 months worth of knowledge in just 1 and a half months..So they professors dont even have that much time to teach everything..so do i write ```<form action="index.html, p1.html, p2.html"/>``` and do i put ```username=localStorage.getItem("username");```inside the if conditiion?

Comment: You can only have one action. It's the page that the form data is submitted to.

Comment: btw i am sorry to bother again and again.. and i really appreciate you are actually trying to help me a lot.. thank for that

Comment: so there arent anyway i could have my username show at all of my html pages?

Comment: You have to add code to all the pages to do this, there's no way to make it happen automatically.

Comment: Once you save it in local storage, all of them can read it.

Comment: ,, i did include the js file in all of my pages